# Предлагаю объединить и синонимизировать PascalABC.NET

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю объединить и синонимизировать внешне идентичные метки [PascalABC.NET](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PascalABC.NET):

- [pascalabc.net](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pascalabc.net) (25 вопросов)
- [pascal-abc](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pascal-abc) (36 вопросов)

Главной сделать метку [pascalabc.net](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pascalabc.net)

Comment: Помню, в [чате уже обсуждали](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=33619987#33619987), но как-то заглохло.

Comment: А он точно до .net'а не существовал?

Comment: Дело в том, что первоначальная реализация Pascal ABC работала без .NET. Об этом можно почитать в [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PascalABC.NET).

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov интересно, а первоначальной реализацией кто-то еще пользуется?

Comment: @Kromster Это уже не важно. Метки не подходят, так как не являются полностью идентичными. Вот я, к примеру считаю, что уже [очень мало кто не использует CSS3 и HTML5 в своей вёрстке веб-сайтов, а использует устаревшие версии и приёмы](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4597/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BC-html5-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BA-html-css3-%D0%BA-css), но это предложение было отклонено.

Answer (score 2):

## Метки не объединяем

> "первоначальная реализация Pascal ABC работала без .NET. Об этом можно почитать в [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PascalABC.NET)"

Comment: Надо бы тогда описания к меткам сделать.

Comment: @PavelMayorov надо бы найти добровольца на это дело ;-)

Comment: Есть существующие вопросы, обсуждающие "первоначальную реализацию"? Стоит заметить, что даже википедия [перенаправляет запрос PascalABC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=PascalABC&redirect=no) на PascalABC.Net.

Answer (score -2):

### **Объединить.**

Но главной сделать [pascal-abc](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pascal-abc).

Comment: Это странно. Зачем бы?